# How to automate the creation of pdf's?

Tags: pdf, automation, csv

I want to create multiple pdf's that look like this :

> "Hello , {Name}!
>
> ... some generic text ..."

where {Name} takes values from a csv file .

How can I automate this process?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Mail Merge either in MS Office or Libreoffice

  Tutorials:

  a.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr0szWDBJYo

  b.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/prepare-your-excel-data-source-for-a-word-mail-merge-990e6516-49bc-4a43-aecc-acd027d92a00
- [image: Menu items to select]
- [image]
- [image: Select a file]
- Accept default
- [image]
- Add the text, and insert fields as needed.
- [image: Goto Finish and Print]
- [image: All records]
- [image: Select virtual printer and click OK]